# Docker - Update fusionauth to latest version

Tags: docker, docker-compose, fusionauth

I have a question regarding the update of fusionauth if i use the docker container (fusionauth-app, auth-search, auth-db). I am actually using version 1.13.2 of the fusionauth app. But i have specified the @latest in docker compose

```
fusionauth:
    image: fusionauth/fusionauth-app:latest

auth-search:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.3.1

  auth-db:
    image: postgres:9.6
```

But how to handle if the new updates comes with changes regarding the database schema or search topic? How to hold all in sync? How are the db migrations handled in that case?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The FusionAuth maintenance mode will handle db schema updates. When this occurs you will be prompted in the web UI to complete the upgrade.

There is an example of the FusionAuth maintenance mode in action in the FusionAuth [5 minute guide](https://fusionauth.io/docs/v1/tech/5-minute-setup-guide) that may be helpful for you to review.

This may not be desired in production with a multi node environment, in this case you can perform the schema updates outside of FusionAuth as part of your upgrade process.

There is an advanced [FusionAuth installation guide](https://fusionauth.io/docs/v1/tech/installation-guide/fusionauth-app#advanced-installation) to help you through this process.

If you are using kubernetes or helm, there are also some advanced configurations that have been contributed by the community to manage schema upgrades automatically. See [helm](https://github.com/FusionAuth/charts) and [k8s](https://github.com/FusionAuth/fusionauth-containers) configurations in our GitHub repo.